# How to get the duration of a video in Python?

Tags: python, video

I need to get the duration of a video in Python. The video formats that I need to get are [MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14), Flash video, [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave), and MOV... I have a shared hosting solution, so I have no [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) support.

What would you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: since you don't have ffmpeg (the answer is unusable), take a look on these other answers: [0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15041103/309483), [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7348505/309483), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11615384/309483), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10075176/309483)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the external command [`ffprobe`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) for this. Specifically, run [this bash command](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Formatcontainerduration) from the FFmpeg Wiki:

```
import subprocess

def get_length(filename):
    result = subprocess.run(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-show_entries",
                             "format=duration", "-of",
                             "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return float(result.stdout)
```

Comment: You can also use `-print_format json` along with `-show_streams` then json.loads the result to get a nice dictionary with all the ffprobe info. This also requires parsing out the extra info printed out by ffprobe(haven't found an option to hide that yet)

Comment: @dennmat: `-loglevel` not `-log_level` (at least with ffprobe 2.3.3)

Comment: python wrapper [ffprobe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffprobe/0.5) might be handy too, `int(float(FFProbe(filename).video[0].duration) * 1000)` gets you miliseconds

Comment: using `ffprobe` Python module, its `from ffprobe import FFProbe; FFProbe('path/to/file').streams[0].duration`

Comment: I am getting an error  `File Not Found` when I run this code. Although file exists.

Comment: Be aware that FFProbe may not work with Python 3 according to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227378/importerror-cannot-import-name-ffprobe)

Comment: As for the accepted answer I was receiving `b'[mpeg2video @ 0xf802d0] ignoring pic cod ext after 0\n1353.984000\n'` in the stdout from some video file. So in my case there were two strings in stdout, which gave me exception in the attempt to convert it to float (`return float(result.stdout)`). The solution that I came up with was `return float(result.stdout.splitlines()[-1])`. It works both for normal and broken files. Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 78):

(**year 2020 answer**)

Solutions:

1. `opencv`  0.0065 sec ✔
2. `ffprobe` 0.0998 sec
3. `moviepy` 2.8239 sec

✔ *OpenCV* method:

```py
def with_opencv(filename):
    import cv2
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

    duration = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
    frame_count = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

    return duration, frame_count
```

**Usage:**  `print(with_opencv('my_video.webm'))`

---

Other:

`ffprobe` method:

```py
def with_ffprobe(filename):
    import subprocess, json

    result = subprocess.check_output(
            f'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 -of json "{filename}"',
            shell=True).decode()
    fields = json.loads(result)['streams'][0]

    duration = fields['tags']['DURATION']
    fps      = eval(fields['r_frame_rate'])
    return duration, fps
```

`moviepy` method:

```py
def with_moviepy(filename):
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
    duration       = clip.duration
    fps            = clip.fps
    width, height  = clip.size
    return duration, fps, (width, height)
```

Comment: Your OpenCV approach is indeed interesting. However it seems prone to errors, returning 0 values often, apparently due to codecs. I haven't been able to count correctly a single file. If you add a few words on that, I would be glad to upvote =)

Comment: It seems it can be fixed by reading fps instead:

        fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        duration = frame_count / fps

Comment: For my videos OpenCV code returned 0 duration. But the frame count value was good, so it was possible to call `fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` and get duration by `frame_count/fps`. OpenCV method is faster than subprocess with ffmpeg, but you have to install a lot of things in your system to get it working. And for me 'pymediainfo' seems almost twise as fast

Comment: opencv is unreliable, see official github issue https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15749#issuecomment-796512723

Answer (score 38):

As reported here https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/2bsnrq/is_it_possible_to_get_the_length_of_a_video/

you could use the moviepy module

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
clip = VideoFileClip("my_video.mp4")
print( clip.duration )
```

Comment: ffpobe is 10 times faster that moviepy.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me.

Comment: This was fast enough for me and simple. Thank you. Note that the units of the output from this code are in seconds.

Comment: Works for URLs as well.

Answer (score 18):

Find this new python library: https://github.com/sbraz/pymediainfo

To get the duration:

```
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('my_video_file.mov')
#duration in milliseconds
duration_in_ms = media_info.tracks[0].duration
```

Above code is tested against a valid mp4 file and works, but you should do more checks because it is heavily relying on the output of MediaInfo.

Comment: Needs separate library (libmediainfo).

Comment: This is the fastest what I found, even faster than moviepy or ffprobe. You're a hero, thanks!!

Comment: You should probably do `max([float(track.duration) for track in MediaInfo.parse('my_video_file.mov').tracks])` to check all tracks because the first track doesn't necessrily have to be the same length as the actually "entire" video.

Answer (score 17):

To make things a little bit easier, the following codes put the output to *JSON*.

You can use it by using `probe(filename)`, or get duration by using `duration(filename)`:

```
json_info     = probe(filename)
secondes_dot_ = duration(filename) # float number of seconds
```

It works on `Ubuntu 14.04` where of course `ffprobe` installed.  The code is not optimized for speed or beautiful purposes but it works on my machine hope it helps.

```
#
# Command line use of 'ffprobe':
#
# ffprobe -loglevel quiet -print_format json \
#         -show_format    -show_streams \
#         video-file-name.mp4
#
# man ffprobe # for more information about ffprobe
#

import subprocess32 as sp
import json


def probe(vid_file_path):
    ''' Give a json from ffprobe command line

    @vid_file_path : The absolute (full) path of the video file, string.
    '''
    if type(vid_file_path) != str:
        raise Exception('Gvie ffprobe a full file path of the video')
        return

    command = ["ffprobe",
            "-loglevel",  "quiet",
            "-print_format", "json",
             "-show_format",
             "-show_streams",
             vid_file_path
             ]

    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
    out, err = pipe.communicate()
    return json.loads(out)


def duration(vid_file_path):
    ''' Video's duration in seconds, return a float number
    '''
    _json = probe(vid_file_path)

    if 'format' in _json:
        if 'duration' in _json['format']:
            return float(_json['format']['duration'])

    if 'streams' in _json:
        # commonly stream 0 is the video
        for s in _json['streams']:
            if 'duration' in s:
                return float(s['duration'])

    # if everything didn't happen,
    # we got here because no single 'return' in the above happen.
    raise Exception('I found no duration')
    #return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_file_path = "/tmp/tt1.mp4"
    duration(video_file_path) # 10.008
```

Comment: before returning jason.loads(out) , out should get decoded into str. 
    `out = out.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: love this solution

Answer (score 13):

Use a modern method with https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python (`pip install ffmpeg-python --user`). Don't forget to install `ffmpeg` too.

Get video info:

```py
import ffmpeg

info=ffmpeg.probe(filename)

print(f"duration={info['format']['duration']}")
print(f"framerate={info['streams'][0]['avg_frame_rate']}")
```

Use `ffmpeg-python` package to also easily create, edit and apply filters to videos.

Comment: Thank you to mention the library reference.

Answer (score 7):

```
from subprocess import check_output

file_name = "movie.mp4"

#For Windows
a = str(check_output('ffprobe -i  "'+file_name+'" 2>&1 |findstr "Duration"',shell=True)) 

#For Linux
#a = str(check_output('ffprobe -i  "'+file_name+'" 2>&1 |grep "Duration"',shell=True)) 

a = a.split(",")[0].split("Duration:")[1].strip()

h, m, s = a.split(':')
duration = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)

print(duration)
```

Comment: A downvote is fine but do have the **courtesy** to explain why ! The code posted above is a **clear cut solution** to the question asked by the OP.

Comment: On a Windows machine, doesn't this answer assume that the user has `ffprobe` on the path? I get that you're just highlighting the lack of `grep` on Windows, but to use that exact syntax, it'd involve editing the environment variables or needs to be run from a the same directory as `ffprobe`.

Answer (score 5):

A function I came up with. This is basically using **only `ffprobe` arguments**

```
from subprocess import  check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT 


def getDuration(filename):

    command = [
        'ffprobe', 
        '-v', 
        'error', 
        '-show_entries', 
        'format=duration', 
        '-of', 
        'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1', 
        filename
      ]

    try:
        output = check_output( command, stderr=STDOUT ).decode()
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        output = e.output.decode()

    return output


fn = '/app/648c89e8-d31f-4164-a1af-034g0191348b.mp4'
print( getDuration(  fn ) )
```

Outputs duration like this:

```
7.338000
```

Comment: This solution replaced my previous code. One copy and paste and my program was working again. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

> As reported here
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/2bsnrq/is_it_possible_to_get_the_length_of_a_video/
>
> you could use the moviepy module
>
> ```
> from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip 
> clip = VideoFileClip("my_video.mp4") 
> print( clip.duration )
> ```

If you're trying to get the duration of many videos in a folder it'll crash giving the error:
AttributeError: 'AudioFileClip' object has no attribute 'reader'

So, in order to avoid that you'll need to add

```
clip.close()
```

Based on this: 
https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/_modules/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.html

So the code would look like this:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
clip = VideoFileClip("my_video.mp4")
print( clip.duration )
clip.close()
```

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 4):

The above pymediainfo answer really helped me. Thank you.

As a beginner, it did take a while to find out what was missing (sudo apt install mediainfo) and how to also address attributes in other ways (see below).

Hence this additional example:

```
# sudo apt install mediainfo
# pip3 install pymediainfo
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('/home/pi/Desktop/a.mp4')
for track in media_info.tracks:
    #for k in track.to_data().keys():
    #    print("{}.{}={}".format(track.track_type,k,track.to_data()[k]))
    if track.track_type == 'Video':
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print("{} width                 {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["width"]))
        print("{} height                {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["height"]))
        print("{} duration              {}s".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["duration"]/1000.0))
        print("{} duration              {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["other_duration"][3][0:8]))
        print("{} other_format          {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["other_format"][0]))
        print("{} codec_id              {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["codec_id"]))
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    elif track.track_type == 'Audio':
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print("{} format                {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["format"]))
        print("{} codec_id              {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["codec_id"]))
        print("{} channel_s             {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["channel_s"]))
        print("{} other_channel_s       {}".format(track.track_type,track.to_data()["other_channel_s"][0]))
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
print("********************************************************************")
```

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Video width                 1920
Video height                1080
Video duration              383.84s
Video duration              00:06:23
Video other_format          AVC
Video codec_id              avc1
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Audio format                AAC
Audio codec_id              mp4a-40-2
Audio channel_s             2
Audio other_channel_s       2 channels
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 4):

Referring to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61572332/17242583) of [@Nikolay Gogol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7673116/nikolay-gogol) using opencv-python (cv2):

His method did not work for me (Python 3.8.10, opencv-python==4.5.5.64) and
the comments say that opencv can not be used in this case which is also not true.

[CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da7c2fa550ba270713fca1405397b90ae0) gives you the millisecond of the current frame that the VideoCapture is at and not the total milliseconds of the video, so when just loading the video this is obviously 0.

But we can actually get the frame rate and the number of total frames to calculate the total number of milliseconds of the video:

```py
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

# the frame rate or frames per second
frame_rate = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# the total number of frames
total_num_frames = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

# the duration in seconds
duration = total_num_frames / frame_rate
```

Answer (score 2):

Open cmd terminal and install python package:`mutagen` using this command

**`python -m pip install mutagen`**

then use this code to get the video duration and its size:

```
import os
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4

audio = MP4("filePath")

print(audio.info.length)
print(os.path.getsize("filePath"))
```

Comment: For me it returns `0.0` for a 5:30 video file. Doesn't handle AVI, and needs different objects for different file types / extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use in prod today, using cv2 way work well for mp4, wmv and flv which is what I needed:

```
try:
    import cv2  # opencv-python - optional if using ffprobe
except ImportError:
    cv2 = None

import subprocess

def get_playback_duration(video_filepath, method='cv2'):  # pragma: no cover
    """
    Get video playback duration in seconds and fps
    "This epic classic car collection centres on co.webm"
    :param video_filepath: str, path to video file
    :param method: str, method cv2 or default ffprobe
    """
    if method == 'cv2':  # Use opencv-python
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_filepath)
        fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        frame_count = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        duration_seconds = frame_count / fps if fps else 0
    else:  # ffprobe
        result = subprocess.check_output(
            f'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 -of json "{video_filepath}"', shell=True).decode()
        fields = json.loads(result)['streams'][0]
        duration_seconds = fields['tags'].get('DURATION')
        fps = eval(fields.get('r_frame_rate'))
    return duration_seconds, fps
```

`ffprobe` does not work for `flv` and I couldn't get anything to work for `webm`. Otherwise, this works great and is being used in prod today.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that like using the **mediainfo** program:

```
import json
import subprocess

#===============================
def getMediaInfo(mediafile):
    cmd = "mediainfo --Output=JSON %s"%(mediafile)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    data = json.loads(stdout)
    return data

#===============================
def getDuration(mediafile):
    data = getMediaInfo(mediafile)
    duration = float(data['media']['track'][0]['Duration'])
    return duration
```

Answer (score -1):

Using ffprobe in a function it returns the duration of a video in seconds.

```
def video_duration(filename):
    import subprocess
    secs = subprocess.check_output(f'ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "{filename}"', shell=True).decode()
    return secs
```