# Get dimensions of a video file

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to get the dimensions of a video file or some other library that would accomplish this? The equivalent of a `Media Info` or something?

Comment: The video module in [Pygame](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html) should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my last company we had similar problem and I couldn't find any python library to do this. So I ended up using [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) from python, media info also has a command line option and it is very easy to parse the output, so practically your python module which uses media-info will be sufficient. It has further advantage because eventually you will find all media-info type software doesn't support all codecs/format so you can use multiple software/libs under the hood with single python wrapper.

Comment: You don't need to launch a process to do this, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15043503/309483).

Answer (score 41):

If I understood you correctly, you mean the resolution of a video for example (768x432).

This could be done simply using opencv in python.

```
import cv2
file_path = "./video.avi"  # change to your own video path
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

How about using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python):

```py
import ffmpeg
probe = ffmpeg.probe(movie_path)
video_streams = [stream for stream in probe["streams"] if stream["codec_type"] == "video"]
```

It gives you a very nice output like this:

```py
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(video_streams[0])
{'avg_frame_rate': '30/1',
 'bit_rate': '3291',
 'bits_per_raw_sample': '8',
 'chroma_location': 'left',
 'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
 'codec_name': 'h264',
 'codec_tag': '0x31637661',
 'codec_tag_string': 'avc1',
 'codec_time_base': '1/60',
 'codec_type': 'video',
 'coded_height': 240,
 'coded_width': 320,
 'color_primaries': 'bt709',
 'color_range': 'tv',
 'color_space': 'bt709',
 'color_transfer': 'bt709',
 'display_aspect_ratio': '4:3',
 'disposition': {'attached_pic': 0,
                 'clean_effects': 0,
                 'comment': 0,
                 'default': 1,
                 'dub': 0,
                 'forced': 0,
                 'hearing_impaired': 0,
                 'karaoke': 0,
                 'lyrics': 0,
                 'original': 0,
                 'timed_thumbnails': 0,
                 'visual_impaired': 0},
 'duration': '71.833333',
 'duration_ts': 6465000,
 'field_order': 'progressive',
 'has_b_frames': 1,
 'height': 240,
 'index': 0,
 'is_avc': 'true',
 'level': 13,
 'nal_length_size': '4',
 'pix_fmt': 'yuv420p',
 'profile': 'Main',
 'r_frame_rate': '30/1',
 'refs': 1,
 'sample_aspect_ratio': '1:1',
 'start_pts': 0,
 'start_time': '0.000000',
 'tags': {'creation_time': '2018-10-26T04:25:07.000000Z',
          'handler_name': 'VideoHandler',
          'language': 'und'},
 'time_base': '1/90000',
 'width': 320}
```

The only downside is that ffmpeg is required, but this should not be a problem in most of the cases.

Comment: actually, there is a better way to do it. You don't need this list comprehension:
`video_streams = ffmpeg.probe(movie_path, select_streams = "v")` should suffice.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'probe'??

Comment: Nevermind. I found the answer PIP uninstall ffmpeg followed by PIP Install ffmpeg-python

Answer (score 4):

This library seems to have an example that does just that on its main page (`print_info(vs)`):

http://code.google.com/p/ffvideo/

It's a wrapper around ffmpeg (there seems to be a few Python libraries for using ffmpeg).

Comment: Doesn't compile anymore, and appears unmaintained

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pure Python tool [`hachoir-metadata`](http://hachoir3.readthedocs.org/metadata.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Get dimensions of a video file.

Usage: get-video-dimensions <video-file>
"""
import sys
from itertools import chain

from hachoir_core.cmd_line import unicodeFilename
from hachoir_metadata import extractMetadata
from hachoir_parser import createParser

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__)

file_metadata = extractMetadata(createParser(unicodeFilename(sys.argv[1])))
print("%sx%s" % next((metadata.get('width'), metadata.get('height'))
                     for metadata in chain([file_metadata], file_metadata.iterGroups())
                     if metadata.has('width') and metadata.get('height')))
```

To install:

```
$ pip install hachoir-{core,parser,metadata}
```

Comment: Quick note for those coming across this later on - hachoir for Python 3 is a different package: http://hachoir3.readthedocs.io/install.html - `pip install hachoir3`

Comment: None of this is working. Not Nick's comment nor the original answer. Cannot install hachoir.

Comment: @Seth you could start here https://pypi.org/project/hachoir/ (likely, the code in the answer can be simplified for that version)

Comment: @jfs, the answer below this one is the correct answer. It simply uses CV2.

Comment: @Seth: there is no "correct" answer. What solution is the best depends on specific circumstances (e.g., a pure Python solution can be installed more easily on more platforms)

Answer (score 2):

There is a python module called pymediainfo - https://pypi.org/project/pymediainfo/
You can use this to get the required metadata of the media file.

Create a directory

```
mkdir supportfiles
```

For some reasons I install the module in target directory called "supportfiles"

```
pip install pymediainfo -t supportfiles/
```

To get the dimension/resolution of the video file

## resolution.py

```
from supportfiles.pymediainfo import MediaInfo
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('/home/sathish/Videos/Aandipatti.mp4')

for track in media_info.tracks:
    if track.track_type == 'Video':
        print ("Resolution {}x{}".format(track.width, track.height))
```

Here is the output

```
[sathish@localhost test]$ python3.6 resolution.py 
Resolution 1920x1080
```

Just in case if you want to know the list of metadata attributes, Here is the solution

## attributes.py

```
from supportfiles.pymediainfo import MediaInfo
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('/home/sathish/Videos/Aandipatti.mp4')
print(media_info.tracks)
for track in media_info.tracks:
    if track.track_type == 'Video':
        print(track.to_data().keys())
    elif track.track_type == 'Audio':
        print(track.to_data().keys())
    elif track.track_type == 'General':
        print(track.to_data().keys())
    else:
        print("No metadata present! or probably file corrupt!")
```

Here is the list of the attributes

```
[sathish@localhost test]$ python3.6 attributes.py 
[<Track track_id='None', track_type='General'>, <Track track_id='1', track_type='Video'>, <Track track_id='2', track_type='Audio'>]

dict_keys(['track_type', 'count', 'count_of_stream_of_this_kind', 'kind_of_stream', 'other_kind_of_stream', 'stream_identifier', 'count_of_video_streams', 'count_of_audio_streams', 'video_format_list', 'video_format_withhint_list', 'codecs_video', 'audio_format_list', 'audio_format_withhint_list', 'audio_codecs', 'complete_name', 'folder_name', 'file_name', 'file_extension', 'format', 'other_format', 'format_extensions_usually_used', 'commercial_name', 'format_profile', 'internet_media_type', 'codec_id', 'other_codec_id', 'codec_id_url', 'codecid_compatible', 'codec', 'other_codec', 'codec_extensions_usually_used', 'file_size', 'other_file_size', 'duration', 'other_duration', 'overall_bit_rate', 'other_overall_bit_rate', 'frame_rate', 'other_frame_rate', 'frame_count', 'stream_size', 'other_stream_size', 'proportion_of_this_stream', 'headersize', 'datasize', 'footersize', 'isstreamable', 'file_last_modification_date', 'file_last_modification_date__local', 'writing_application', 'other_writing_application'])

dict_keys(['track_type', 'count', 'count_of_stream_of_this_kind', 'kind_of_stream', 'other_kind_of_stream', 'stream_identifier', 'streamorder', 'track_id', 'other_track_id', 'format', 'format_info', 'format_url', 'commercial_name', 'format_profile', 'format_settings', 'format_settings__cabac', 'other_format_settings__cabac', 'format_settings__reframes', 'other_format_settings__reframes', 'internet_media_type', 'codec_id', 'codec_id_info', 'codec', 'other_codec', 'codec_family', 'codec_info', 'codec_url', 'codec_cc', 'codec_profile', 'codec_settings', 'codec_settings__cabac', 'codec_settings_refframes', 'duration', 'other_duration', 'duration_firstframe', 'other_duration_firstframe', 'bit_rate', 'other_bit_rate', 'width', 'other_width', 'height', 'other_height', 'stored_height', 'sampled_width', 'sampled_height', 'pixel_aspect_ratio', 'display_aspect_ratio', 'other_display_aspect_ratio', 'rotation', 'frame_rate_mode', 'other_frame_rate_mode', 'frame_rate', 'other_frame_rate', 'minimum_frame_rate', 'other_minimum_frame_rate', 'maximum_frame_rate', 'other_maximum_frame_rate', 'frame_count', 'resolution', 'other_resolution', 'colorimetry', 'color_space', 'chroma_subsampling', 'other_chroma_subsampling', 'bit_depth', 'other_bit_depth', 'scan_type', 'other_scan_type', 'interlacement', 'other_interlacement', 'bits__pixel_frame', 'stream_size', 'other_stream_size', 'proportion_of_this_stream', 'color_range', 'colour_description_present', 'color_primaries', 'transfer_characteristics', 'matrix_coefficients'])

dict_keys(['track_type', 'count', 'count_of_stream_of_this_kind', 'kind_of_stream', 'other_kind_of_stream', 'stream_identifier', 'streamorder', 'track_id', 'other_track_id', 'format', 'format_info', 'commercial_name', 'format_profile', 'codec_id', 'codec', 'other_codec', 'codec_family', 'codec_cc', 'duration', 'other_duration', 'bit_rate_mode', 'other_bit_rate_mode', 'bit_rate', 'other_bit_rate', 'channel_s', 'other_channel_s', 'channel_positions', 'other_channel_positions', 'channellayout', 'samples_per_frame', 'sampling_rate', 'other_sampling_rate', 'samples_count', 'frame_rate', 'other_frame_rate', 'frame_count', 'compression_mode', 'other_compression_mode', 'stream_size', 'other_stream_size', 'proportion_of_this_stream', 'default', 'other_default', 'alternate_group', 'other_alternate_group'])
```

Hope this will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the dimensions directly from the windows metadata:

```
import win32com.client
def get_dimensions(path,file):
    sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application', 0)
    ns = sh.NameSpace(path)
    item = ns.ParseName(file)
    height = ns.GetDetailsOf(item,314)
    width = ns.GetDetailsOf(item,316)
    return [height, width]

dimensions = get_dimensions("C:\folder","video.avi")
```

To get a full overview of available attributes, you can try:

```
attributes_list = []
for i in range(330):
    attributes_list.append([ns.GetDetailsOf("",i), ns.GetDetailsOf(item,i)])
print(attributes_list)
```