# Obtain the duration of a mp4 file

Tags: python, mp4

I need to know the duration of a mp4 file with python 3.3. I search and try to do this with enzyme, atom, but i can't find the way to obtain these.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [How to get video duration in Python or Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-video-duration-in-python-or-django) might help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A number of previously answered questions deal with this issue:

- [How to get the duration of a video in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-video-duration-in-python-or-django)
- [Get total length of videos in a particular directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041103/get-total-length-of-videos-in-a-particular-directory-in-python)
- [Get dimensions of a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348505/get-dimensions-of-a-video-file)
- [mpeg-2 library to extract video duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615384/mpeg-2-library-to-extract-video-duration)
- [Python native library to read metadata from videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075176/python-native-library-to-read-metadata-from-videos)

Comment: Thanks, i don't find these answer before. when i try to use the solution of the first link, y obtain these error:  File "C:\Users\garanda\Desktop\py.py", line 28, in <module>
    getLength('C:/videosFinal/000/Cam01.MP4')
  File "C:\Users\garanda\Desktop\py.py", line 25, in getLength
    return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
  File "C:\Users\garanda\Desktop\py.py", line 25, in <listcomp>
    return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: I have to confess that I have not tried the code in those pages myself. I'm sure they will help you if you post your problem as a comment on the related answer. It may help if you be more explicit about your code and [format it so it reads easier](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown).