# Is it possible to get time length from af .mkv and .mp4 file from OS

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to make a script that pick up a random mkv or mp4 file in a directory and play, only limit is that the file playtime must not be more than 2 hours, how do I do that? 
A newbee and just startet but my code looks like this:

`import os
from random import choice
directory = 'D:\Johnny-3 Film 2018'
files = os.listdir(directory)
for i in range(100):
    movie = choice(files)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will need to use an external proram. You could use [`ffprobe`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) or [`moviepy`](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/). There are many examples from similarly asked questions that I found from [`this stack overflow answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20098026/10231083):

- [How to get the duration of a video in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-video-duration-in-python-or-django)
- [Get total length of videos in a particular directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041103/get-total-length-of-videos-in-a-particular-directory-in-python)
- [Get dimensions of a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348505/get-dimensions-of-a-video-file)
- [mpeg-2 library to extract video duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615384/mpeg-2-library-to-extract-video-duration)
- [Python native library to read metadata from videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075176/python-native-library-to-read-metadata-from-videos)

Comment: Starting programs is not what program_ming_ is about - Stack Overflow is for programming, and this answer should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If anything, only libraries should be named.