# how to get the file size of a video which is in file system using filesizeformat of django?

Tags: django, django-templates

how to get the file size of a video which is in file system using filesizeformat of django?

```
    `{{ db.vid|filesizeformat }}` 
     returns only the size of the path.
```

Comment: i stored video in file system and path in database.here vid contains the path of the video.

Answer (score 0):

If `vid` is a `FieldField` then try this:

```
{{ db.vid.file.size|filesizeformat }}
```

Comment: how to get the duration of a video file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-video-duration-in-python-or-django

Answer (score 0):

filesizeformat as it's name states (and as the official documentation describes) is formatting a file size value and not displaying the filesize itself.
If you used the build in File Field for uploading the video, then you can use the already provided .size attribute.

```
{{db.vid.file.size}}
```

More information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.size
And:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat