# Get .mp4 file length Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, metadata, mpeg-4

I want to get the video length metadata of .mp4 files, using either a module that comes with Python or a module available on PyPi and doesn't require external software. I've searched all over the internet, and all I could find was either modules that don't support .mp4 files, outdated and non-functioning modules, and modules that require external software.

It only has to be able to run on Windows*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the duration of a video in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-the-duration-of-a-video-in-python)

Comment: It's already asked here [How to get the duration of a video in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-the-duration-of-a-video-in-python)

Comment: And it doesn't have an answer that fits my specifications.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [moviepy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moviepy).

First, install it using `pip`:

```
$ pip install --user moviepy
```

Then, from python, make sure you have the ffmpeg binary installed (only required once, but harmless if you call it multiple times):

```
>>> import imageio
>>> imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Then you can use `VideoFileClip` to query and manipulate the file:

```
>>> clip = VideoFileClip('/path/to/file.mp4')
>>> duration_in_sec = clip.duration
>>> duration_in_sec
14.0
```

Comment: Like I said, no external software*

Comment: If you're ruling out pip, the most recognized source for external libraries, you won't get very far. Your question is like "How can I drive without a vehicle?"

Comment: I'm not ruling out pip. I'm ruling out non-pip stuff like ffmpeg

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice the download function call. I thought you were ruling out the use of pip libraries. If you edit the question, I can take back my downvote. At the same time, I'm wondering if the reason python itself doesn't is unable to do this has something to do with codecs... Still, you'd think you could read the metadata easily enough. Hmm...