# How to get the length of a video from the properties > detail in python

Tags: python, operating-system

I wanted to get the length/duration of a video using python, I tried using the

`os.stat(filename)`

but it doesn't seem to be working. Please help.
[this is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKSk7.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-the-duration-of-a-video-in-python/38042336

Comment: @kgiannakakis I would like to get it via the "os" if it's possible, and I've tried that one too, it didn't work for me well.

Comment: It isn't possible with os.stat. This returns POSIX file information, the same for all file types.

Comment: @kgiannakakis aight thanks for the time man.